# Very strange behavior of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Please edit the title if you know the actual problem behind this.
I'm facing a very strange behavior with pointers in C.

Version 1 (What I want but the output is not what I expect):

```
void *partial_evolve(void * pars)
{
    evolve_pars *p = (evolve_pars*)pars;
    unsigned char *in = *p->grid_in;
    unsigned char *out = *p->grid_out;

    for (int t = 0; t < p->time_steps; ++t)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < p->dim_y; ++y)
         for (int x = p->start_x; x < p->end_x; ++x)
           evolve(in, out, p->dim_x, p->dim_y, x, y);

       swap(&in, &out);
       pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    }
}
```

Version 2 (The output is right but I have to use two waits which I do not want):

```
void *partial_evolve(void * pars)
{
    evolve_pars *p = (evolve_pars*)pars;

    for (int t = 0; t < p->time_steps; ++t)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < p->dim_y; ++y)
         for (int x = p->start_x; x < p->end_x; ++x)
           evolve(*p->grid_in, *p->grid_out, p->dim_x, p->dim_y, x, y);

       pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
       swap(p->grid_in, p->grid_out);
       pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    }
}
```

The input struct that I use is:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int dim_x;
    unsigned int dim_y;
    unsigned char **grid_in;
    unsigned char **grid_out;
    unsigned int start_x;
    unsigned int end_x;
    unsigned int time_steps;
    int is_master_thread;
} evolve_pars;
```

The swap function:

```
void swap(unsigned char **a, unsigned char **b)
{
    unsigned char *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Regardless of the rest of the code, the pointer operation of the partial_evolve function in both cases should behave the same. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Why use `void *`? That means losing information for the compiler

Comment: @EdHeal: It is probably a callback function.

Comment: @leppie - Perhaps - but not specified in the question

Comment: It's a thread. It has to be void *. Besides that, there is no problem for using void * as long as you cast it right. Am I right on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, the `swap()` function is called with the address of 2 local pointers.

```
swap(&in, &out);
```

In the second version, the parameters are part of the structure

```
swap(p->grid_in, p->grid_out);
```

Comment: What is the problem with that? Could you explain more please?

Comment: @Hamid The problem is that you act on local (temporary ot the context) data and not changing the actual data inside your evolve_pars struct

Comment: I really do not understand what you mean. Do you mean the swap function is not swapping the pointers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the result of swap on both cases is the same.

Comment: The first swap does not change the contents of the struct; you cannot see changes in the calling function.

Comment: @pmg That's my intention. I do no need to swap the addresses in the actual input. since other threads are using them. I need to change the address on the local pointers only and the swap function does it. I even tested it with a printf: `printf("1 - %p %p %p %p\n", *p->grid_in, *p->grid_out, in, out ); swap(&in, &out); printf("2 - %p %p %p %p\n", *p->grid_in, *p->grid_out, in, out );` The output is: 1 - 0x1a8c010 0x1a8d9d0 0x1a8c010 0x1a8d9d0 2 - 0x1a8c010 0x1a8d9d0 0x1a8d9d0 0x1a8c010